# Sorting a list by length of its elements

Tags: r

Sorry for basic question, but i have a list of elements, which are numeric vectors

```
str(list1)
    List of 34
     $ 1      : num [1:2037171] 98.3 98.2 98.1 97.4 97.9 98 97.7 98.1 98.4 98 ...
     $ 3      : num [1:692076] 98.8 98.1 97.6 96.6 96.4 96.9 96.1 95.8 96.7 96.5 ...
     $ 2      : num [1:82621] 97.7 97.7 97.4 97.7 98.4 98.1 97.4 98 97.6 98.3 ..
     .
     .
     .
```

, it seems that list.sort(or order) does not work, because list1 is not an atomic vector. I want to sort list1 by the length of its vectors.
How is that possible? Sorry for "abusing" this site as my personal R tutorial. couldnt find the answer on google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
len <- sapply(list1, length)
list1[order(len)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over the list to get the lengths:

```
mylist <- list(1:5, 1:10, 1:2)
mylist[order(sapply(mylist, length))]
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: How everybody in here seems to use `sapply` instead of `vapply`?

Comment: You can of course use `vapply` for this, but I don't see an urgent need.

Comment: Of course. On the other hand, I strongly think that the use of `sapply` should be discouraged, since it is slower and doesn't assure the value to be of a given type. I think it is much better to use `lapply` or `vapply` depending on what we want as output.

Comment: If you want to use `vapply` here you have to consider that `length` can return a double for very long vectors. I don't expect that the list will be so long that the speed difference between `sapply` and `vapply` matters for this task. At least, the question doesn't indicate that.

Comment: In this case of course the difference won't be noticeable. I'm just wondering why almost everybody in here use `sapply` without any upside (aside from typing another argument in the call), while it can have very bad consequences in many instances. I consider it a bad habit. Am I wrong? Do I miss something?

Comment: The danger of bad consequences is somewhat exaggerated by your comments. Of course, `vapply` is "safer". However, you also have to consider the additional didactic burden.